# Click Listener not triggered on CardView

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener, cardview

I have created a recyclervuew which contain Cardview as below:

item.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/tileLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="130dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/brand06"
        app:cardCornerRadius="15dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/actionLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="110dp"
            android:color="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/editLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="110dp"
            android:color="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_margin="5dp">
```

When I am building the layout in the recyclerview, every time i am creation an item using `item.xml`, I am tagging `tileLayout` with a specific name using the command:

```
        tileLayout.tag = name.toString()
```

name is an enum define as below:

```
enum class Name { 
        ITEM1,
        ITEM2,
        EDIT,
    }
```

I have added a logic to check the name and when `EDIT` is seen, I make `actionLayout` GONE and set `editLayout` VISIBLE

I register the `onClickListener` on `tileLayout`. It seems that when the `editLayout` is visible and `actionLayout` GONE, the click is not working in `tileLayout`. when I do the opposite, the click is registered properly

I do not see why.

Any idea?

Comment: remove clickable & focusable property from card view and please add recycler view code as well

Comment: The problem is occurring because of height & width set match parent

Comment: @hasan  actionLayout works. Only editLayout failed

Comment: Is editLayout inside of actionLayout ???

Comment: CardView can only have one children